# Capybara session not preserved with an api callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I have a rail 5 app with capybara 2.13 feature specs. One spec completes a three-part transaction flow that includes a redirect url to a callback path in the app. I save the transaction ID in the session as `session[:current_transaction_id]` and then use this to look up the transaction when processing the callback. This works fine in development but when testing with capybara the `session` hash is missing `:current_transaction_id`.

I've unsuccessfuly tried wrapping my spec as described in 
https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#using-sessions

```
Capybara.using_session("User session") do
  # log in and complete a transaction
end
```

How can I get the session to persist through the given spec?

Comment: Capybaras `using_session` doesn't refer to the `session` you're asking about.  It refers to a browser or browser/app pair instance used by Capybara and would commonly be used if you needed to simultaneously log two different users into an app while testing it (chat, realtime status updates, etc).   Are you using cookie based sessions? If so are you sure the (sub)domains originally being visited (where you set the transaction id) and the one redirected to are the same (at least to the level the session cookie is set at)?  If not fix that, if they are add test code to you question.

Comment: It was a domain issue! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, added as an answer so you can mark the question as completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capybaras using_session doesn't refer to the session you're asking about. It refers to a browser or browser/app pair instance used by Capybara and would commonly be used if you needed to simultaneously log two different users into an app while testing it (chat, realtime status updates, etc).

When using cookie based sessions you need to make sure the original (sub)domains originally being visited (where you set the transaction id) and the one redirected to are the same (at least to the level the session cookie is set at). If they aren't the session cookie will no longer be valid for the redirect request (and not sent) and hence the transaction id not available.